# Update a filed mongo document based on a value from another document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to update the value in matching document based on a value of another document in this collection, but matching different filter.

So let's say I have 2 documents:

```
{
  name: 'My Doc',
  path: 'some_path',
  rootId: Root Doc Id,
},
{
  name: 'Root Doc',
  path: '/',
  rootId: null,
}, 
{
  name: 'New Root Doc',
  path: '/',
  rootId: null,
}
```

now I need to set a rootId of My Doc to reference New Root Doc _id matching some filter. Like this:

```
{
  name: 'My Doc',
  path: 'some_new_path',
  rootId: New Root Doc Id,
},
```

So I want my query to look like:

```
{
   updateMany: {
     filter: { path: 'some_path' },
     update: {
       $set: {
           rootId: { query to find the value of a New Root Doc Id based on some filter}
       },
       $set: {
           path: 'some_new_path',
       }
   }
}
```

Is it possible in bulkWrite updateMany operation?

Comment: The question is not clear to me, where did `New Root Doc Id` came from, it is not in the collection...The generic answer to the title of your question is: "Yes, you can use `$lookup`"

Comment: @nimrodserok in the same collection, just another document

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is no, you can't use other document values within a proper update operator.

What you can do is use an aggregation pipeline and finishing it with the [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) stage, However this kind of update is not atomic, so if this is important for your logic you'll have to use transactions or add another logical layer in your app.

Comment: I'm doing it as part of migration

Comment: If it's a migration one type script then aggregation with `$merge` sounds like the way to go.

Comment: I use mongo driver and bulk write, may I ask you to show me an example.